# What is the difference between lazy var normal instantiation and closure instantiation?

Tags: swift, closures, lazy-initialization

```
lazy var propertyOne: BabyYoda = BabyYoda(delegate: self.mandalorian)
```

vs.

```
lazy var propertyTwo: BabyYoda = {return BabyYoda(delegate: self.mandalorian)}()
```

Is one more efficient than the other? Do they compile down to the exact same code?
I understand that `propertyTwo` allows for additional lines of code (e.g. setting up additional things in the `BabyYoda` object), but that's the only difference I can think of.

Comment: And that is indeed the only difference. See http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_computed_initializer

Comment: They’re effectively the same thing. But you’d generally only use the closure syntax if you needed multiple lines to configure it. Otherwise the closure only adds unnecessary syntactic noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second syntax, which I call “define and call”, is the legal way to initialize an instance property using several lines of code.

Note that, per se, none of that has anything to do with `lazy`, which is irrelevant to the particular question you pose. The `lazy` is effectively just a way of making it legal to say `self.mandalorian` in this instance property initializer. That's interesting, but it's a totally different matter.

Comment: I suppose I am more curious about the differences between the compiled LLVM bitcode. I would check myself, but I have no idea how to view/find the bitcode Xcode generates. But from your answer and Rob's comment, my understanding is that it literally doesn't matter which syntax I use, one just looks busier than the other. Also, dependencies on self for initialization is notably interesting (for good or bad, I'm not sure)

Comment: Neither of us said it literally doesn’t matter, especially for the actual code you gave. Creating and calling a function means overhead.

Comment: Dependencies on self is irrelevant to the question, as I told you. But it is why you must use `lazy`.